# Is there anyone here who has been using the ironOcr library for a long time?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, pdf, ocr

Is there anyone here who has been using the ironOcr library for a long time? Address: https://ironsoftware.com/
I have a trial license for one month.
The ocr library works very well, but only for a few hours and then it starts throwing an exception on the line:

```cs
OcrResult Result = Ocr.Read(Input); //System.AccessViolationException occurs here
```

I tried several times to start a new project with ironOcr via Nuget Package Manager. I tried different versions (builds) of Windows, Visual Studio and dotnet.

Comment: The exception you encounter seems like a permissions issue.  What is `Input` when this happens?

Answer (score 0):

After some time I worked out a solution. Now the pdf processing process is quite stable.
The solution was to purchase a license. The trial license somehow works, but after processing a large number of files, ironOcrch starts strangely.
Another problem, although somewhat less important, is not to try to read too long pdf files. In my case, I limited the number of pages to a maximum of 30.